# Docker: OCI runtime create failed + executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: docker

Boa noite pessoal,

Tenho quebrado a cabeça aqui para usar corretamente o `dockerfile` e o `docker-compose`.

Eu tenho a imagem `getjv/nodejs:8.11.4`,
sempre que ela iniciar (container) já quero levantar o servidor *Node* com o comando: `npm start`.

Mas quando passo isso em um `dockerfile` ou um `docker-compose` recebo um:

```
ERROR: for pasta_backend_1  Cannot start service backend: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"npm start\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

Dei um `docker inspect` e realmente o npm não tá no path da imagem,  mas quando eu acesso o container ai o comando funciona normalmente.

Eu já li e reli varias dicas, mas não consegui levantar o container e já mandar o comando.

Segue aqui meu docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  frontend:
    image: getjv/nodejs
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
    volumes:
      - D:\xxxxxx:/home
  backend:
    image: getjv/nodejs:8.11.4
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - D:\xxxxxxxx\api:/home
    entrypoint:
      - npm start
```

Obrigado a todos.

Comment: Você precisa usar essa imagem do NodeJS mesmo? Porque a própria documentação da imagem sugere você entrar no container e executar o servidor.

Comment: hahaha, é pq essa imagem é minha, eu que to usando ela na unha pq não consigo configurar o serviço para levantar o contêiner e rodar na mão. por isso perguntei aqui.

Comment: Então, você pode criar um dockerfile, apontar pra ele no docker-compose.yml e criar um "ENV PATH=<local_do_seu_npm>". Já tentou?